# How to perform healthcheck for an Angular container based on node.js?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile, health-check

I'm trying to perform a healthcheck for an Angular container. Here is the Dockerfile for it:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:ssr 

FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json /app
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /app/dist
ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

As far what have I done is to add this into server.ts file:

```
server.get('/health', (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).json({ status: 'OK' });
      console.log('Received GET request to /health endpoint');
    });
```

And here is my healthcheck from docker-compose.yml:

```
test: "curl -f http://localhost:4000/health || exit 1"
interval: 1m30s
timeout: 10s
retries: 3
start_period: 40s
```

When I run http://localhost:4000/health in my browser I receive 200 OK as I should (and there are logs proving it was received), however when it is performed through executing "docker compose up" command it does not work. What may be the reason for that?

Comment: "however when it is performed in docker containers" how is it performed there?  can you show request and response from docker containers? or do you mean the docker compose health check?

Comment: @erik258 I meant when it is performed through executing "docker compose up" command and using the healthcheck above. I'll edit the description.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment and this post is 4 months old, but this worked for me:

```
        healthcheck:
          test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--fail", "-G", "http://localhost:4200" ]
          interval: 30s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 30
```

This just pings the app module hosted at root and if the angular code is running it returns some javascript. Im thinking about setting the interval even lower because in my current stack there are about 8 containers that all need to spin up before the frontend. If you want the interval to be 1:30, you might be waiting a while for it to run it's healthcheck, that is, if I understand how these intervals work.

edit: 4200 is the port we are forwarding to, so my docker override file has this for the container:

```
ports:
  - '4219:4200'
```